# Scoverage: contribute code coverage to multiple modules

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest, scoverage

I have a multimodule maven project on Scala. I want to write an integration test in module **A** that calls a method **XXX** of some class from this module. This method in its turn calls a method **YYY** from some class in another module **B**.
As a result of `scoverage:report` I want to see that coverage for both **XXX** and **YYY** is not empty.

However currently **YYY** is shown as not covered (coverage is 0%)

Is it possible to configure `scoverage` for that?

Comment: To a  degree `coverageAggregate` task after address that but it is not perfect. Does running it helps you?

Comment: It is not supported by scoverage-maven-plugin

Comment: `scoverage:report` has `aggregate` parameter, there is no separate task, but it probably will not work because aggregation aggregates reports, not raw coverage data.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
mvn scoverage:package // creates classes prepared to coverage instrumentation
mvn scoverage:report // creates coverage report
```

Comment: use `scoverage:report-only` as the second goal